# reading from HTML and inserting in form

Tags: php, html, automation

I have to read the content from HTML file and then the parameters for different heading should be entered into the form in php and then i need to save the page and submit it so that it will be saved in the databse.
 I need to automate this whole process since i have approx 2000 HTML files which should be read and should be entered in a form in PHP. Do you have any idea about any tool which can help in this process. small idea will be also helpful.
                  Note : i can not enter the contents from HTML directly into the databse from back end since there are many fields which are getting auto generated when i am saving and submitting the form.

thanks in advance.

Comment: hey! What have you tried, do you have any starting point?

Comment: no... i am not getting any idea about any tool which can help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the html file using DOM approach
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Use curl library to automate the process
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php